# Stop emacs auto complete from flashing cursor in other windows

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

When I'm typing in an emacs window and auto complete *isn't* giving me an auto complete suggestion the cursor blinks on both the window I'm typing in and all other windows. I've found the [manual](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Change_colors) which seems like it should be what I need but I can't figure out a correct configuration to stop the blinking. How can I disable the cursor from blinking?

Comment: Hi, for me the cursor turns red momentarily is this the behavior you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, each time I type a character when ac is not finding a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you observe is fuzzy matching in action read about it [here](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Completion_by_Fuzzy_Matching). Basically whenever auto-complete cannot complete at point it tries to complete using fuzzy match, if completion succeeds it turns the cursor red momentarily. You can disable fuzzy matching completely by adding the following to your init file (see [manual](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#ac-use-fuzzy))

```
(setq ac-use-fuzzy nil)
```

OR

If you want to keep fuzzy matching and just disable the [blink](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#ac-fuzzy-cursor-color) you can add the following to your init file

```
(setq ac-fuzzy-cursor-color nil)
```